# Can only the registrars name server hos the SOA record for a new domain?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration

Say I have registered domain `my-domain.example`

Am I right that only the registrar NS server where I've registered the domain have SOA record describing `my-domain.example` domain and therefore is the authoritative server for `my-domain.example`?

Comment: This meanders a bit - you start by saying your domain is my-domain.com but then reference my_website.pl? What do you mean by 'only authoritative server'?

Comment: Typically, your registrar is the SOA for your domain name. It has to be that way at least at first. It is possible to change your SOA, however, unless you know DNS cold I do not recommend using other DNS servers. There would be no advantage. In fact, half of the DNS questions that I see here are a result of messing up a SOA change that was not necessary and mostly done for vanity or out of ignorance.

Comment: @Yhorian Sorry I've indeed messed domain names up. Corrected now. So can You answer if my registrar is the only one having SOA record describing my-domain.com?

Answer (score 2):

Any authoritative DNS server can potentially have a SOA record for `my-domain.com`. However, only *the* authoritative DNS provider is the one that will be serving that SOA record.

The authoritative DNS server is determined by the delegation at the registry (configured from the registrar). When you point the name servers for a domain at the registrar to the specific DNS provider A, then A will become the authoritative DNS provider for the domain.

Clients will connect to one of the authoritative servers for the provider A (as specified by the name server entries) and fetch the relevant DNS records (including the SOA) from that provider.

But nothing prevents you to have the zone configured elsewhere. In fact, if you are switching from provider A to B, you will likely have the zone (and SOA) in both providers. However, only one will be authoritative, the delegated one.

Answer (score 0):

Your registrar keeps an SOA record of your domain. The SOA record has information such as your DNS nameservers. Your DNS nameservers are provided to you by your webhosting company.